# How to set up emr_default in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Dear Stackoverflow member, 
I am trying to use Airflow to schedule a DAG that launch a cluster, run some spark jobs then terminated itself. I tried to follow this example: 
https://insight.io/github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/example_dags/example_emr_job_flow_automatic_steps.py 
It gave me the error: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The conn_id `emr_default` isn't defined
I probably need to have `emr_default` set up (please correct me if this is not the case). Does anyone have try this before and give me some hints on how to set it up? Airflow website doesn't provide too much on emr connection: http://pythonhosted.org/airflow/configuration.html?highlight=connection#connections

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the airflow UI, go to Admin -> Connections tab, and edit the values for emr_default row.

Comment: Thanks @Him, I found out the issue, I was using an old version then upgrade to 1.8, there was no emr_default before as a variable

Comment: I just want to add that once using aws_default and emr_default, ~/.aws directory will be where the aws configuration will be taken. So make sure you have it there.
More info:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html#default-connection-ids

Answer (score 1):

As@Him said, you can edit in airflow.
but if you can't find `emr_default`, you can go to `Admin` -> `Connections` -> `Create` to add any connection you want

Comment: Thanks @zhongjiajie, but I already accepted another answer, but still want to thanks for your contribution.